# Changing background color on recyclerview item also changes color in couple of view below in the list

Tags: android

The way I handle clicks on my list items is that I implement (OnClickListener, OnLongClickListener) on ViewHolder class and I define needed methods and everything works fine. When I long click I set background color of that view and it works fine. Now the problem is, I suspect because of the way that recycler view reuses views, when I scroll down my list , there is another view that also changed its background color , for example , If I long click item #2, item #13 will also change its background color.

This is my view holder class :

```
 private class CrimeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {
        private TextView mCrimeTitle;
        private TextView mCrimeDate;
        private CheckBox mCrimeSolved;
        private View mView;

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            mMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_delete_crime).setVisible(true);
            isLongClicked = true;
            mSelectedItem = getAdapterPosition();
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#6A6160"));
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(isLongClicked == true){

                mMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_delete_crime).setVisible(false);
                mLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(mSelectedItem).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E0E0E0"));
                isLongClicked = false;
            }
            else{

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CrimePagerActivity.class);
            //intent.putExtra(CRIME_ID_EXTRA, mCrimes.get(getAdapterPosition()).getmCrimeID());
            intent.putExtra(CRIME_POSITION_EXTRA, getAdapterPosition());
            startActivity(intent); }
        }

        public CrimeViewHolder(View view){
             super(view);
             mView = view;
             view.setOnClickListener(this);
             view.setOnLongClickListener(this);
             mCrimeTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_crime_title);
             mCrimeDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_crime_date);
             mCrimeSolved = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.list_crime_solved);

             mCrimeSolved.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                     mCrimes.get(getAdapterPosition()).setmSolved(isChecked);
                 }
             });


        }
    }
```

OnBindViewHolder code :

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(CrimeViewHolder holder, int position) {

            holder.mCrimeTitle.setText(mCrimes.get(position).getmTitle());
            holder.mCrimeDate.setText(mCrimes.get(position).getmDate().toString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
            holder.mCrimeSolved.setChecked(mCrimes.get(position).ismSolved());

        }
```

Comment: Can you post your onBindViewHolder() code?

Comment: there it is, originaly didnt post because it does not do anything highlighting related

Comment: In my opinion you should create a selector in drawable and use it as a background of your list item.
The drawable should contain resources for both pressed and not pressed state

Comment: I will try that

Comment: Can you please post the answer. I am too struggling with similar issue.